# How to reuse a title tag using Thymeleaf with layout?

Tags: html, layout, thymeleaf

How to change a Layout to reuse the same title text from Template on other tags, avoiding duplicate the text on Template file? See example:

Having this Layout:

```
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title from LAYOUT</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Title from LAYOUT</title>
        <th:block layout:fragment="content">Default content</th:block>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this Template:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="layout">
    <head>
        <title>Title from TEMPLATE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <th:block layout:fragment="content"><p>My content</p></th:block>
    </body>
</html>
```

The desired rendered page is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title from TEMPLATE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Title from TEMPLATE</title>
        <p>My content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution adding a fragment block in the `h1` and including it with the `layout:include="this :: title"` property in the title element.

Layout:

```
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title layout:include="this :: title">Title from LAYOUT</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><th:block layout:fragment="title">Title from LAYOUT</th:block></h1>
        <th:block layout:fragment="content">Default content</th:block>
    </body>
</html>
```

Template:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="layout">
    <th:block layout:fragment="title">Title from TEMPLATE</th:block>
    <th:block layout:fragment="content"><p>My content</p></th:block>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have 2 multiple ( HTML & Head & Body & Title) tags on the same page, you should remove on of them and keep every thing inside one Body,

Comment: Agreed, the layout and the template should actually be one in the same, and there should be a file that is something along the lines of "desiredPageContent.html" that is being placed where it is supposed to go in the body... Unless I'm understanding the situation wrong, but your def. right @Noor Adnan! :)

Comment: Having multiple, head, body, ecc tags on both files is a common practice to static prototyping, allowing to see a correctly rendered html page when the html file is opened on the browser. Thymeleaf uses a element merging feature (see https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect#head-element-merging).

Answer (score -1):

Doing this requires more than just HTML/CSS.  I will provide my example in PHP (A server side language) but note that you can use Javascript or any other compiled scripting web language such as python, pearl, Ruby on rails (Probably, never used it before), JSP (Java Server Side Pages) and more... So here is the code that would answer your question, if you have PHP installed on your server. :)

```
<?php $myTitle = "This is my title!"; ?>

<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo $myTitle; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php echo $myTitle; ?></title>
    <th:block layout:fragment="content">Default content</th:block>
</body>
```

What is happening here? In PHP on line 1, your declaring a variable to equal a bit of text... down in your html, with the line:  your executing a little bit of PHP to output whatever is in that variable $myTitle.  PHP is executed on the server, and is NOT sent to the user viewing the page, so if you look for  on any website you won't find it...

Comment: Thank you to you answer. In dynamic languages reusing the same variable is easy to archive the result, but the question is about using template inheritance feature of Thymeleaf.